# User name of the GitHub account is not displayed as the author of the commits

Tags: git, github

Recently I noticed that all my commits for a git repository in gitHub are showing a wrong name (`not my account user name, which normally a hyperlink to my profile`)

So there will be a **blue question mark** which has a tooltip saying *`"Invalid author email. If this commit was made by you, check your local git email setting."`*

So I did some change [which was indicated here.](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/)

```
git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"
```

And after that my commits will have my user name as author name and it will act as the hyperlink.

But the problem is all my other previous commits were remains unchanged. Is there any way I can change those as well. ? (i.e. to set my user name as the commit author)

Answer (score 1):

So you used a different email address as user.email on the original commits?

If yes, then I think you can fix that by associating that email address with your GitHub account (see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account/) on how to do that).

Comment: no. Actually I haven't done `git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"` this step before. So all the commits show just my name. (Not Hyperlink to my profile )
after I add the --global user.email it worked and now the user name of the profile is displayed. But the old commits remain unchanged. (the author of them though I did those)

Comment: @prime take a look at [Commits are not linked to any user](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/#commits-are-not-linked-to-any-user) and see if that is of any help.

Comment: Yes this was the problem. My commits are just like as in the image. So I did add an email address. (like I have mentioned in the question)
After that commits will show the correct user name with the link. But older commits will not change :/

Comment: Did you try navigating to the old commits (by clicking the commit message link for them) that haven't changed and hover over the blue question mark to see why the commit is not linked?

Comment: yes. there it said `"Invalid author email. If this commit was made by you, check your local git email setting."` After I add an valid email address new commits will have that but the previous ones wont change. How can I change them also ?

Comment: I think the only way to do that is to [change the author info](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/).

Comment: Is it recommended or risky ?

Comment: Depends if any other users have forked your repo, and if you know the old email used. If your repo was forked it's bad practice to rewrite history. If you don't know the original email used then the script won't work.

Comment: Several users already forked the repo and have contributed. Will this affect their contributions ? What are the consequences for them and for me if I do that ? 
btw thank you very much for the guide :)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149499/what-happens-when-you-rewrite-history-of-a-public-branch). They'd basically have to discard all the changes they made as their repo would be broken, then manually re-apply the changes. I wouldn't mess with the repos history just for a profile link.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your name

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
```